# Python: how to read variables from another process?

Tags: python

So i'm building a custom machine learning simulation and wanting to read certain values from a training process, in another one to visualize real time training data.

So for example, the training simulation has an array of values under a data structure. Let's say the data structure is an instantiated class called `data`. Inside this class, there is a list of values, let's call it `values`.

This simulation has a training loop, so while that training loop is going, I would like to run another script that can query `data.values` and do something with it.

Is this possible? - Ideally I would like to keep my simulation code as is so as to not add necessary bulk.

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind "have you tried a fork?", I might be wrong though

Comment: Maybe you can setup communication between your processes using a socket. Did you read this : https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipc.html ?

Comment: @Eggplant what do you mean by a fork?

Comment: @Antwane I think a socket would be the way to go, but I would also like a route where I can effectively read the memory from one process to another soas to be a more general solution. But for my problem, this may be the way to go.

Comment: The solution suggested by @SBylemans (RabbitMQ) could also be really useful. You should have a look at it ;)

Comment: @DyllanM I thought forking your process would help, but now I remember that fork only initially copy variables from the parent process. So you wouldn't be able to read changes anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a message queue for that. Add the value to the queue in your loop process and read and visualize with the other application. Take a look at [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html)

Comment: Hmm, this seems promising. I'll have to try it out when I'm able. Thanks for the recommendation.